# A rest webservice address with equal sign

Tags: rest, resteasy

I have a REST webservice, and I want to execute an URL with such parameter:

```
http://localhost:8080/Students/StudentsWS/students_schedule/?link=StudentsDisplay.aspx?StudentID=3
```

If you've noticed it, there is an equal sign in the passed parameter.
The server is just receiving that address, with no `=3` characters:

```
http://localhost:8080/Students/StudentsWS/students_schedule/?link=StudentsDisplay.aspx?StudentID
```

Is there any solution to pass that equal sign ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: To build on @SLaks answer, you should always encodeURIComponent when passing parameters in a URL and decode them on the server. encodeURI will fail to escape certain characters that the component one does.

Comment: @skishore: I don't think he's using Javascript.  (but you're completely correct)

Comment: @sLaks: honestly, I did not understand your answer. Do you mean that I change "=" with "3D" (hexadecimal value) ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: @sLaks: I did this `http://localhost:8080/Students/StudentsWS/students_schedule/?link=StudentsDisplay.aspx?StudentID%3d3` but it's not working.

Comment: @sLaks: I found a tool that encode any URL, and it gave me this:`http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FStudents%2FStudentsWS%2Fstudents_schedule%2F%3Flink%3DStudentsDispl%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bay.aspx%3FStudentID%253d3` , tried to execute it with fail. Any hint please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL address must be changed to:
`http://localhost:8080/Students/StudentsWS/students_schedule/?link=StudentsDispl‌​ay.aspx?StudentID%3d3`
And then the server has to decode that URL to have the `=` sign another time. For example, in JAVA, we can do this:

```
result = URLDecoder.decode(link, "UTF-8");
```

That's it.